# jQuery.post: does it fire any event?

Tags: jquery

I trying to do an "automatic" load indicator.. for that, I want to listen for ajax events on the application, and show/hide the indicator.

My only problem with this right now, is that  I don't know what events jquery trigger when it's doing some ajax call (`$.ajax`, `$.post`, `$.get`...)

Docs say anything about it. How can I do that without add extra code to all my calls?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can try using `ajaxStart` method http://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/global-ajax-event-handlers/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can get access to that via [`ajaxSetup`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajaxSetup/). There's also [`ajaxStart`](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxStart/), [`ajaxStop`](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxStop/), and many others described in [the documentation](http://api.jquery.com).

Comment: thanks, i din't understand that I can manage they that way.. at first, I  understood that they're just callbacks.

Answer (score 1):

yes it fires the callbacks.
$.ajax has the following callbacks: success, error, complete.
check the documentation for more http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/